# Accessing SSR HTML Head and Body through Specific APIs in a NuxtJS Project

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

In my NuxtJS project, I am setting up a functionality where end users can access the server-side rendered (SSR) HTML of a specific page. They can do this by using two distinct API endpoints:

- For the head section: `https://demo.com/${pageName}/api/getHTML/head`
- For the body section: `https://demo.com/${pageName}/api/getHTML/body`

These APIs are designed to extract either the head or body part of the HTML content, depending on the endpoint used, from the SSR output of any given page. I am looking for advice or best practices on implementing these APIs efficiently and effectively in the NuxtJS framework.